# Автоматический выход с аккаунта?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Есть сайт, на нем есть авторизация, при каждой авторизации в базу добавляется токен. Так вот, как скажем при удалении токена из базы, аккаунт вылетал на том устройстве, где этот токен есть? Если будет не сложно, покажите пожалуйста примером. Хочу сделать активные сеансы и возможность выйти.

Comment: При удалении записи, добавляете запись в табличку(можно триггер повесить), из которой нода читает(а если удаление инициирует сама нода, то возможно и не потребуется), как только нода нашла удаленный токен, отправляет клиенту сообщение, что токен протух. Клиент, получая уведомление удаляет токен у себя и рвет связь. Примером можно показать, если вы покажите, как и где вы храните токены, как взаимодействуете с БД, как токены проверяются и так далее.